# Case Milestone - Upload via DataLoad / Bulk Create

Tags: apex, case, casemilestone, entitlements

I have created Case Milestones - First Response, but due to some criteria mismatch no records were created.

Now we have corrected the criteria and the First response is being executed/completed for the New records but for the existing or Old records this First response was never hit/completed.

User wants us to Load Case Milestone - First Reponse records in salesforce. Is this possible using DataLoad or any other way that we can create those records.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot create case milestones using dataloader; Currently we can only update the milestones.

You can check is there any auto-complete logic written in process builder or apex class which is completing this milestones.

Regards,
Akanksha.